# Is it possible to load windows 10 with minimum amount of drivers?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, safe-mode

my win10 system got stuck at the circle turning forever and I can't even boot into the safe mode! I suspect there's something wrong with my driver as the ntbtlog showed a lot of recurring "NOT_BOOT" entries.

So what I'm trying to find out is, is it possible to load win10 with the bare minimum drivers?

If that's only possible in safemode, which I can't boot into, then it's bad.

Please help!

Also, is it a good idea to uninstall all the driver packages that failed to load using DISM?

Comment: I posted an answer to use msconfig which you should be able to do from a Startup Repair.   If not, then you need to reinstall windows. Hopefully you can put your disk in a carrier to get your documents before reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boot disk seems to have encountered a catastrophic error.

Your first priority should be to recover any needed data for which you
do not have backups. You could do that by booting a Linux Live USB.

Once your data is safe, create a Windows boot USB and
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If that doesn't help, or if the Windows boot cannot locate the Windows
version that is installed on the disk, then the disk is lost.
You will need to format it using slow format (not quick) and
reinstall Windows from scratch.

If the format or the Windows installation fails because of disk errors,
then the disk is unusable.

Comment: Hi harry thanks for the answer! I solved the problem using RE, and SFC managed to fix a damaged file and I managed to remove a problematic driver package, but I suppose the disk WAS damaged as it loads noticeably slower than before. Thanks so much! I'm glad I didn't do a clean install like before and lose everything.

Comment: sure thing! You got it